# PHP syntax error, help please

Tags: php, syntax, syntax-error

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';' on line 11, i am trying to locate my mistake, but no success. As i followed tutorial, and code is 1/1 as video, i don't understand what is wrong.I'm at PHP beginner level , so can anyone help to fix this ?

```html
<?php
        if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    
     include_once 'dbh.inc.php';
    
     $first = mysql_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['first']);
     $mail = mysql_real_es1cape_string($conn, $_POST['mail']);
     $pwd = mysql_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['pwd']);
    
     if (empty($first)||(empty($mail)||(empty($pwd)) {
      header("Location: signup.php?signup=empty");
      exit();
     }
     else  {
      if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z]*$/", $first)){
       header("Location: ../index.html?signup=invalid");
       exit();
      } else {
       if (filter_var($mail, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){
        header("Location: ../index.html?signup=empty");
        exit();
       } else {
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE users_mail='$mail'";
        $result = mysql_query($conn, $sql);
        $resultCheck = mysql_num_rows($results);
    
        if($resultCheck > 0) {
         header("Location: ../index.html?signup=emailalredyinuse");
         exit();
        } else {
         $hashedPWD = pasword_hash($pwd, PASWORD_DEFAULT);
         $sql = "INSERT INTO users (user_first, user_mail, User_pwd) VALUES ('$first', '$mail', '$hashedPWD');";
         $result = mysql_query($conn, $sql);
         header("Location: ../index.html?signup=succsess");
         exit();
        }
       }
      }
     }
    
    } else {
     header("Location: ../index.html");
     exit();
    }
```

Comment: `mysql_real_es1cape_string`?

Comment: There are quite a few other typos. `es1cape`, `pasword`, etc. Also, the `mysql_` functions have been deprecated for years, and are not included in PHP 7, which will soon be the only supported PHP version.

Answer (score 0):

You have a mistake in if statement, this line:

```
if (empty($first)||(empty($mail)||(empty($pwd)) {
```

Should be:

```
if (empty($first)||empty($mail)||empty($pwd)) {
```